# Checking Console.ReadLine is empty without assigning it to a variable

Tags: c#

I would like to parse the result of Console.ReadLine to float, and handle the possibility of it being null too.

It could be done in 2 lines.

However, I would like to do it within 1 line.

Is there any way to check a Console.ReadLine() without first assigning it to a variable.

For example:

```
var total = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine() == null ? "0" : Console.ReadLine())
```

My example is wrong as I simply repeated the Console.ReadLine().

The correct format to the question I derived from is:

```
string? input = Console.ReadLine();
total = float.Parse(input ?? "0");
```

Is there any way to actually do it within one line?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

@
*Edit

Turns out I need to check for totally empty and whitespaces just in case too.
and the whole chunk becomes:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldValue))
      fieldValue = "0";
floatAccVal = float.Parse(fieldValue);
```

Comment: You can simply write `total = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? "0");`. It fits your needs?

Comment: There is **no** advantage to doing this in one line other than possibly reducing the number of characters you type. Once your code moves to a release build, the optimizer (in the JIT compiler) will remove unneeded temporary variables. The advantage of your two-line version is that it's clear that the first line is prompting the user, while the second one is doing the conversion. Also, once you realize that it's much better to use `float.TryParse` (rather than `.Parse`), you'll likely need to use two lines anyway

Comment: `float.Parse(input ?? "0")` <- are you sure this's what you are expected? `Console.ReadLine` only returns `null` from reading external input, it will return `""` when you just press enter from the keyboard.

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure, that it will return null in response to `<ctrl>+Z`

Comment: @Flydog57: There can definitely be advantages to doing things in a single *expression*... for example in order to initialize a field. Now initializing a field using `Console.ReadLine()` would be very odd indeed - but the broader point about it being useful to be able to express something in a single expression is still important IMO.

Comment: @Flydog57 There **can** be an advantage, though...beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Some people just prefer concise code. Advantages can be subjective. I love your comment about `ctrl-Z`...I was about to respond that `ReadLine` *never* returns `null`. Then I tested your comment and decided not to be wrong. :)

Comment: @shingo, you are right

Comment: JFYI `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` will check for empy strings also.

Answer (score 4):

Although there is no much benefits to use it in one line comparing to that fact that code is getting harder to read, it is possible to do it by using next code:

```
var total = float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out float value) ? value : 0;
```

**UPD**: if you don't wont to allocate the memory for additional variables, you can use the next code:

```
float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var value);
```

In case if `ReadLine()` cannot be parsed, the `value` will be set to `default`, that is `0` for `float`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line, using pattern matching to introduce a variable as part of a condition:

```cs
float f = Console.ReadLine() is string line ? float.Parse(line) : 0f;
```

That *does* introduce a new variable - but it's still within a single line.

Your original code of `float.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? "0")` would also work.

If you want to handle an *empty* string in the same way, pattern matching can handle that easily too, although it's slightly more fiddly at this point and I'd probably use an `if` statement unless I had a particular reason not to:

```cs
float f = Console.ReadLine() is string line && line != "" ? float.Parse(line) : 0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this is to recreate something similar to Kotlin's [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) in C#, specifically [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html). These basically let you turn almost anything into a single expression.

```
public static class ScopeFunctions {
    public static R Let<T, R>(this T t, Func<T, R> block) => block(t);

    // others that might be useful
    public static void Let<T>(this T t, Action<T> block) => block(t);
    public static T Also<T, R>(this T t, Func<T, R> block) {
        block(t);
        return t;
    }
    public static T Also<T>(this T t, Action<T> block) {
        block(t);
        return t;
    }
}
```

The two lines you showed can then be written as:

```
var result = Console.ReadLine()?.Let(line => float.Parse(line)) ?? 0;
// or this, which I find less readable but is shorter
var result = Console.ReadLine()?.Let(float.Parse) ?? 0;
```

In practice though, I would go with `TryParse` like in Ivan Vydrin's answer, as that is a lot more idiomatic C# than borrowing some Kotlin feature, and also handles invalid inputs.